# How to pin context in the top of the buffer window?

Tags: plugin-coc, lsp

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MICJH9fn6e4) and at around 35 minutes the person shows a feature to display the current context in the top few lines. I tried searching for a plugin or a setting in coc or default nvim to do just that, but I couldn't find anything. I want a similar thing to happen with c++.

It looks like this.

[image]

Note that the relative lines are not consecutive at the top and it shows the current blocks the person is currently in. How do I accomplish that same thing? As a bonus, can there be a highlight (such as underdouble) to show that the code in question is not actually above the current block of code I'm looking at?

I tried searching for "vim coc display function context at the top" or "vim lsp show context at the top" and similar, but nothing useful came up.

I wish to keep using coc. Is there a plugin or feature that does that? I know vim airline does display the current function and tagbar highlights the current function, but I'd also like a bit more context on the top as shown in the picture/video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is the [context](https://github.com/wellle/context.vim) or the [nvim-treesitter-context](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter-context) plugin.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: You are Welcome :-) I have added a mapping to toggle the extension and when I'm lost reading a too long function I turn it on. I find the extension very useful. Thanks for the feedback :-)